# How can I SSH after establishing a connection with ruby net/ssh gem

Tags: ruby, ssh, net-ssh

I have 2 systems I work with that are daisy chained. System A is what I have to connect to initially, then I ssh into system B to run commands to view status of services and other things. I work doing field support on these systems and have no way to change the way they work in regards to creating APIs or how we connect to them.

What I want to do is have a ruby script that can get into system B to run some commands and then pass the output from those commands back into my laptop automatically.

I can use ruby gem net/ssh to get into system A and run commands but I cannot figure out how to ssh into system B after I am in system A. This is what I have right now.

```
    Net::SSH.start('123.456.78.9', 'username', password: 'password') do |ssh|
        # some how ssh into system b
    end
```

I tried just `ssh.exec! "ssh 123.456.78.30"` but that does not work. I tried nesting another `Net::SSH.start` call but that doesn't work either.

Finally, I'd also like to scp files from system B back to a /tmp folder in system A but I can't get that to work either. That's a whole other thing but if anyone has any advice on that I would appreciate it.

Also just a note that the password I put in the script isn't the actual password. When ruby net/ssh runs and it hits the wrong password the shell prompts for a password and I put the actual one in. Maybe I can do that a less hacky way but right now it's not the priority.

Comment: Are you able to SSH from terminal? SCP?

Comment: @Azeem Yes I ssh all the time using terminal through A into B, but I can't figure out the right syntax or gem to use to get into B using the ruby script. I can also scp files from B to A and then A to my laptop.